# iOS - Run async operations in serial manner on non-main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void) fetchOperation:(NSString *c){
    async_method(c):^{
      NSLog(@"%@ completed.",c);
    }
  }
// call fetchOperation:@"A"
// call fetchOperation:@"B"
// call fetchOperation:@"C"

//Expecting output: A completed, B completed, C Completed.
```

Please note I want fetch to happen on non-main thread. Their could be 1 to n fetchOperation calls. And each fetchOperation call can happen as a result of some other user action like user tapped.
I tried semaphores, nsoperationQueue but no luck so far.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

Comment: I tried using dispatch serial queue with dispatch_async but it starts fetchOperation immediately rather than waiting for first one. So I added semaphore in fetchOperation to block until I get response but then subsequent calls are not even queued sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the basic idea that you had tried semaphores sounds good.

I like to use the extendable approach, where you can easily extent the amount of operations being performed, where you pass all the parameters (or other operation related information) from an array.

Simple and easy extendable function!

```
- (void)performBatchProcess
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSArray *attributes = @[@"A", @"B", @"C"];
        NSLog(@"Started all Operations at: %f",CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent());
        [self performSelectorWithAttributes:attributes success:^{
            NSLog(@"Finished all Operations");
            NSLog(@"Finished at: %f",CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent());
        }];
    });
}
```

This function is basically used to queue all the operations sequentially

```
- (void)performSelectorWithAttributes:(NSArray<NSString *> *)attributes success:(void (^)())success
{
    for (NSString *attribute in attributes)
    {
        [self performOperationWithAttributeAndWait:attribute];
    }
    success();
}
```

Your basic function is included here with its success block being used to stop blocking the queue

```
- (void)performOperationWithAttributeAndWait:(NSString *)attribute
{
    //create a semaphore
    __block dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    void (^privateFinish)(NSString *attribute) = ^(NSString *attribute) {
        NSLog(@"Finished Process: %@",attribute);
        // Stop blocking our thread and go on :-)
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    };

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"Started Process: %f",CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent());
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2]; // Simulate a process that takes time
        privateFinish(attribute);
    });
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
```

Sample log, which demonstrates that an operation takes at least 2 seconds now (with the timer simulating the process calculations)

```
2017-03-29 00:05:02.570 asdasd[24376:1836160] Started all Operations at: 512431502.570876
2017-03-29 00:05:02.571 asdasd[24376:1836146] Started Process: 512431502.571429
2017-03-29 00:05:04.598 asdasd[24376:1836146] Finished Process: A
2017-03-29 00:05:04.599 asdasd[24376:1836146] Started Process: 512431504.599392
2017-03-29 00:05:06.673 asdasd[24376:1836146] Finished Process: B
2017-03-29 00:05:06.673 asdasd[24376:1836146] Started Process: 512431506.673433
2017-03-29 00:05:08.673 asdasd[24376:1836146] Finished Process: C
2017-03-29 00:05:08.674 asdasd[24376:1836160] Finished all Operations
2017-03-29 00:05:08.674 asdasd[24376:1836160] Finished at: 512431508.674475
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't wait for first call to finish. It starts second call even though first one has not returned yet. I want second call to start when first one has finished.

Comment: Added some extensive logging for your processes, The processes are being processed sequentially (not parallel), else the timer would not hold the next operation to start. :-)

Comment: [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2] blocks the main thread right? So it will always wait before going ahead.

Comment: No, it blocks the current thread, in which it is called. In this case, a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

Give the function a completion handler as part of it's interface...

```
- (void)fetchOperation:(NSString *)string completion:(void(^)(void))completion {
    async_method(string):^{
        NSLog(@"%@ completed.",string);
        if (completion) completion();
    }
}
```

Then make the calls nested...

```
[self fetchOperation:@"A" completion:^{
    [self fetchOperation:@"B" completion:^{
        [self fetchOperation:@"C" completion:^{
            NSLog(@"all done");
        }];
    }];
}];
```

**EDIT** To handle an arbitrary set of params, create a function that takes an array and calls itself recursively...

```
- (void)manyFetchOperations:(NSArray *)parameters completion:(void(^)(void))completion {
    if (!parameters.count) return completion();
    NSString *nextParam = parameters[0];
    NSArray *remainingParams = [parameters subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, parameters.count-1)];
    [self fetchOperation:nextParam completion:^{
        [self manyFetchOperations:remainingParams completion:completion];
    }];
}
```

Call it as follows, for the same effect as nesting...

```
[self manyFetchOperations:@[@"A", @"B", @"C"] completion:^{}];
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that their could be 1 to n fetchOperation calls. And each fetchOperation call can happen as a result of some other user action like user tapped. Updated the question.

Comment: I'll show you how to do that when I get back to a dev machine. Basically, we build one that takes an array of strings (params to this one) and calls itself recursively.

Comment: @Raj - edited to illustrate a general form for sequential async calls

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation for [maxconcurrentoperationcount](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsoperationqueue/1414982-maxconcurrentoperationcount) property of [NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsoperationqueue?language=objc) .

> The maximum number of queued operations that can execute at the same
>   time.
>
> The **default** value of this property is
>   **NSOperation​Queue​Default​Max​Concurrent​Operation​Count**.

Setting it to `1` should only run one at a time as you need.

Edit:

To make sure you wait for the other to complete you should look into [dependencies](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsoperation/1416668-dependencies?language=objc)

> This property contains an array of NSOperation objects. To add an object to this array, use the add​Dependency:​ method.
>   An operation object must not execute until all of its dependent operations finish executing. **Operations are not removed from this dependency list as they finish executing**. You can use this list to track all dependent operations, including those that have already finished executing. **The only way to remove an operation from this list is to use the remove​Dependency:​ method.**

and [addDependency](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsoperation/1412859-adddependency) and KVO observing [isReady](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsoperation/1412992-ready) , `is​Finished` among others as you need it.

Good sources for more information and details on the properties above:

- [Tutorial](http://lorenzoboaro.io/2016/01/05/having-fun-with-operation-in-ios.html)
- [Tutorial](http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/) (by Mattt)
- [Apple WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/226/)

Comment: Executing one at a time is fine. But As the operation itself is asynchronous, it will happily add next operation without knowing if previous one was completed.

Comment: Thanks for diverting me to NSOperation/Queue world. I got it working with both custom NSOperation and custom NSOperationQueue classes. In custom NSOperationQueue class I keep reference to previous op and add it as a dependency for the current operation. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Raj No worries! I am that I could help :) If you want you can mark as the answer so the community can see it solved. EDIT: I see you marked another answer already, no worries.

Comment: I end up using dispatch solution but your solution works too. SO allows to mark only one post as an answer. But cheers for your solution :)